# Wordpress not correctly cropping thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have Thumbnails and sizes enabled as so in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', 150, 150, true );
add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 360, 300, true );
```

They are correctly called in the loop, and although crop is set to true, I have yet to see any image cropped to the specified sizes, they all do it "seemingly" proportional. I regenerate the thumbnails every time I make a change and nothing works. I've searched a lot for the answers and there are almost no fixes (I don't want to have to use a plugin and do it manually).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
   add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', 150, 150, true );// please give another name if its not major requirement of this
   add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 360, 300, true );// please give another name if its not major requirement of this
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why this is any different, but it finally works. Thanks again.

Comment: This code is functionally no different to your original code - it must have been something else you did that fixed it (I'm experiencing the same issue)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. Still searching for a solution.